# How to group error bars

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to reproduce this plot using pgfplots. I can generate a bar plot with error bars. However, if i specify marks only, error bars share the same xtick labels overlap.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to make this work with bar plots either. But here is a solution without them. It uses `x expr={\thisrow{x}+dx}` where `dx` is a small number, which is added to the x value to shift it. With this, the error bars can be grouped similar to bar plot. The downside: you have to manually shift each plot this way.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
  error bars/.cd,
    x dir=none,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
}
\begin{axis}[
    width=10cm,
    height=5cm,
    only marks,
    tick pos=lower,
    tick align=outside,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4},
    xticklabels={A,B,C,D,E},
    y tick label style={rotate=90},
    xlabel=method,
    ylabel=error,
  ]
  \addplot+ [mark=*] table [x expr={\thisrow{x}-0.1}, y=y, y error=ey] {
    x y ey
    0 0.3 0.04
    1 0.2 0.03
    2 0.4 0.04
    3 0.1 0.02
    4 0.2 0.03
  };
  \addplot+ [mark=*] table [x expr={\thisrow{x}+0.1}, y=y, y error=ey] {
    x y ey
    0 0.4 0.05
    1 0.3 0.02
    2 0.4 0.03
    3 0.2 0.04
    4 0.3 0.04
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```